# different XML Data on html page

Tags: html, xml, xslt, feed, spry

I have different XML files in my intranet which is getting refreshed every 5 min & Data get changed on every refresh  interval.., i want to create a HTML page where i can show all my XML feed.
what is a best way to create & load different XML feed on a single page
I am using Spry in Dreamweaver.. this code is working in IE but not in firefox

```
    <html xmlns:spry="http://ns.adobe.com/spry"><body background="SpryAssets/mantra.jpg">
<p>
  <script  src="SpryAssets/xpath.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
  <script  src="SpryAssets/SpryData.js" type="text/javascript">
</script>
  </div>
</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<table width="852" align="center" border="0">
<tr>
      <th width="740" scope="col"><strong class="Fn">Now playing </strong></th>
      <th width="102" scope="col"><a href="index.html" title="Reload" target="_parent" class="rm1"><span class="Fn">Reload</span></a></th>
  </tr>
</table>
</p>
<table width="850" border="0">

</table>
<script  type="text/javascript">
var Agra = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("http://59.90.73.143/Agraexport.xml", "nexgen_audio_export/audio");
var Bareilly = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("http://59.90.73.143/bareillyexport.xml", "nexgen_audio_export/audio");
var Gorakhpur = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("http://59.90.73.143/Gorakhpurexport.xml", "nexgen_audio_export/audio");
var Hisar = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("http://59.90.73.143/Hisarexport.xml", "nexgen_audio_export/audio");
var Jalandhar = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("http://59.90.73.143/Jalandharexport.xml", "nexgen_audio_export/audio");
var Karnal = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("http://59.90.73.143/Karnalexport.xml", "nexgen_audio_export/audio");
var Ranchi = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("http://59.90.73.143/Ranchiexport.xml", "nexgen_audio_export/audio");
var Varanasi = new Spry.Data.XMLDataSet("http://59.90.73.143/VARANASIEXPORT.xml", "nexgen_audio_export/audio");
</script>
<div spry:region="Agra">
  <table width="852" align="center" bgcolor="#252525" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
    <tr>
      <th width="99" class="Fn" spry:sort="type">City</th>
      <th width="427" class="rm1" spry:sort="title"><span class="Fn">Title</span></th>
      <th class="Fn" spry:sort="artist">Artist</th>
    </tr>
    <tr spry:repeat="Agra">
      <td><div align="center" class="rm1">
        <div align="left">Agra</div>
      </div></td>
      <td class="rm1">{title}</td>
      <td class="rm1">{artist}      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div spry:region="Bareilly">
  <table width="852" align="center" bgcolor="#252525" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
      <tr spry:repeat="Bareilly">
        <td width="99"><div align="center" class="rm1">
          <div align="left">Bareilly 
          </div>
        </div></td>
        <td width="429" class="rm1">{title}</td>
        <td class="rm1">{artist}</td>
      </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</div>
<div spry:region="Gorakhpur">
  <table width="852" align="center" bgcolor="#252525" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
      <tr spry:repeat="Gorakhpur">
      <td width="99"><div align="center" class="rm1">
        <div align="left">Gorakhpur</div>
      </div></td>
        <td width="429" class="rm1">{title}</td>
        <td class="rm1">{artist}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div spry:region="Hisar">
  <table width="852" align="center" bgcolor="#252525" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
      <tr spry:repeat="Hisar">
      <td width="99"><div align="center" class="rm1">
        <div align="left">Hisar</div>
      </div></td>
        <td width="429" class="rm1">{title}</td>
        <td class="rm1">{artist}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div spry:region="Jalandhar">
  <table width="852" align="center" bgcolor="#252525" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
      <tr spry:repeat="Jalandhar">
      <td width="99"><div align="center" class="rm1">
        <div align="left">Jalandhar</div>
      </div></td>
        <td width="429" class="rm1">{title}</td>
        <td class="rm1">{artist}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div spry:region="Karnal">
  <table width="852" align="center" bgcolor="#252525" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
      <tr spry:repeat="Karnal">
      <td width="99"><div align="center" class="rm1">
        <div align="left">Karnal</div>
      </div></td>
        <td width="429" class="rm1">{title}</td>
        <td class="rm1">{artist}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div spry:region="Ranchi">
<table width="852" align="center" bgcolor="#252525" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
      <tr spry:repeat="Ranchi">
      <td width="99"><div align="center" class="rm1">
        <div align="left">Ranchi</div>
      </div></td>
        <td width="429" class="rm1">{title}</td>
        <td class="rm1">{artist}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
<div spry:region="Varanasi">
<table width="852" align="center" bgcolor="#252525" border="1" cellpadding="1" cellspacing="2">
      <tr spry:repeat="Varanasi">
      <td width="99"><div align="center" class="rm1">
        <div align="left">Varanasi</div>
      </div></td>
        <td width="429" class="rm1">{title}</td>
        <td class="rm1">{artist}</td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The best way is to use XSLT to convert your data in to html, so that you point each file at the stylesheet and get out the html you want

Comment: My XML data is getting refreshed every 5 min.. so i think converting to XSLT will not solve my problem..